# How To Pass a Record to Angular Pipes

Tags: angular, enums, record, angular-pipe

I'm trying to pass a record to an Angular pipe, but I cannot get rid of the parser error:

**Parser Error: Unexpected token 0, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 32 in [ {{ dto.status | mapEnumToText: { 0: 'Ok', 1: 'Error', 2: 'Review' } }} ]**

```js
<div>
    {{ dto.status | mapEnumToText: { 0: 'Ok', 1: 'Error', 2: 'Review' } }}
</div>
```

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

export type enumToTextMapType = Record<number, string>;

@Pipe({
  name: 'mapEnumToText',
})
export class MapEnumToTextPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, enumToTextMap: enumToTextMapType): string {
    console.log(enumToTextMap);
    return enumToTextMap[value];
  }
}
```

My goal is to specify a mapping of enum values to texts.
I know that I could also do *ngIf for each of the enum values, which is not very concise. 
Specifying the map in the ts-File works, but I want to put all the texts in the html file. 
`myEnumMap: enumToTextMapType = { 0: 'Ok', 1: 'Error', 2: 'Review' };`

The numbers 0, 1, 2 are just for testing right now and will be replaced with enum keys.

Comment: Is it the same when you test it with any? (enumToTextMap: any)

Comment: @Carsten yes, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your pipe. Template statements and template expressions looks like javascript, but isn't. There are many small limitations.

Define `{ 0: 'Ok', 1: 'Error', 2: 'Review' }` as variable in component class and use in template as argument for pipe.

Comment: thanks. The template statement seems to be the limiting factor here and I havent found a documentation of what works and what not. Arrays with tuples could work, but code-completion did not work and an exhaustiveness-check is missing. So I created the record in the component class and referenced it in the html.